# Count entries with Timestamp in postman

Tags: count, postman

I want to count how many records with Today's date time stamp. I have below response.
But when execution done I am getting count = 0 but it should be 1. What is wrong with my script?

Response Body

```
[
    {
        "id": 373,
        "user_id": 119118855,
        "location_id": 9999,
        "duration": 0,
        "watts": 0,
        "timestamp": "2019-07-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        "equipment_id": 53,
        "name": "10 Ride",
        "equipment_name": "Bike2"
    },
    {
        "id": 376,
        "user_id": 119118855,
        "location_id": 9999,
        "duration": 0,
        "watts": 0,
        "timestamp": "2019-06-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "equipment_id": 53,
        "name": "10 min Ride",
        "equipment_name": "Bike2"
    },
    {
        "id": 338,
        "user_id": 119118855,
        "location_id": 9999,
        "duration": 0,
        "watts": 0,
        "timestamp": "2021-03-30T00:27:07.000Z",
        "equipment_id": 53,
        "name": "20 min Ride",
        "equipment_name": "Bike"
    },
]
```

Here is my Postman script

```
const moment = require("moment")
var now = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
var timestamp = moment(jsonData.timestamp).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
console.log("timestamp is" + timestamp)

var count2 = jsonData.length
pm.test("Check workouts for this user during today",function () {
for (var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
 if(jsonData[i].equipment_id === 53){
    count2 = jsonData.filter( a => a["timestamp"] == now).length
    } }
   console.log("Today's workout Count:"+ count2);
   
pm.test("There are "+ count2 +" workouts for this user during today" );
});
```

I write the console for timestamp and it display today's date correctly. I want to compare only with date. Time not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Javascript expert, so not sure what your `filter( a => a["timestamp"] == now)` is doing/ is supposed to do.

Simply comparing a substring of the `timestamp` in the JSON with the timestamp you calculated does the trick:

```
const moment = require("moment")
var now = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
var timestamp = moment(jsonData.timestamp).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
console.log("timestamp is " + timestamp)

var count2 = 0
for (var i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++) {
    if((jsonData[i].equipment_id === 53) && (jsonData[i].timestamp.substring(0,10) == timestamp)){
         count2++
    }
}

console.log("Today's workout Count: "+ count2);
```

Also, for a real test, you need an assertion:

```
pm.test("Workout count equals 1", function () {
    pm.expect(count2).to.equal(1)
});
```

PS.: This is not working today anymore, you need to manipulate one of the timestamps in the JSON to match `today()`. Took me a bit to figure that one out... ;-)

Comment: Hi Christian, Thanks for the reply. this works very well. Again I want to know how many records earlier. So I tried with same if statement with not equal option.  if((jsonData[i].equipment_id === 53) && (jsonData[i].timestamp.substring(0,10) != timestamp)) But still it gives me total number of records. But still return total number of records